# RxJS interval, AJAX request and reduce

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to figure out how to send AJAX requests every five  seconds while mapping the data and reducing it using RxJS operators.

So, there's a simple Angular service that requests an external API for astronauts that are in space at the moment: http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json

In the service, I try to first set the `interval(5000)` and then use an RxJS mapping operator to map the incoming number to a GET request.

The task is this: I need to first get astronauts, then find those who are flying on ISS, and then those astronauts I can render into a view. The data must be updated each 5 seconds; so I need to re-send the same HTTP request each 5 seconds, which I can do with `setInterval()`. And this is not the cleanest solution to the problem.

Here's the code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, concatMap, flatMap, map, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Astronaut } from '../models/astronaut.model';

const astronautsUri = 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IssLocatorService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAstronauts(): Observable<Astronaut[]> {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      concatMap(num => this.http.get(astronautsUri)),
      flatMap((newAstronauts: any) => newAstronauts.people),
      filter((astronaut: Astronaut) => astronaut.craft === 'ISS'),
      map((astronaut: Astronaut) => [astronaut]),
      reduce((prev, next) => [...prev, ...next]),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
}
```

The code doesn't work, alas.
Although the flow do gets to the `reduce()` operator, the operator doesn't return to the `subscribe()` method in the component.

It seems to me, though, that the solution should work fine. Here's how I think it works:

1. After 5 seconds the first number 0 is produced and the outer Observable gets mapped to an inner Observable - an AJAX request. `concatMap()` waits until the inner Observable completes and only then does it get the second number - 1.
2. The inner Observable is an HTTP request that returns JSON. I need only the people from the object that looks similar to this: `{success:true, people: [...]}`), so then I use `flatMap()` to transform this object to the array of astronauts `people`. Each object in `people` then becomes an Observable due to how `flatMap()` works.
3. I filter each astronaut object.
4. I map each astronaut object to an array to be reduced.
5. I reduce the astronauts array. In other words, the `astronauts.people` gets reproduced thanks to `reduce()`.
6. (Here's the problem) `reduce()`, according to the specification, should return to `subscribe` because the inner Observable has completed. **But it doesn't**: `reduce()` waits until the next number is produced by `interval()` and is mapped to an inner Observable, again `people` are returned and pushed to the same array. And it goes on and on.

If I replace `reduce()` with `scan`, the array or astronauts **does** get returned to the `subscribe` method. However, this array continually gets larger due to astronaut objects being repeatedly pushed into it.

The following approach works just fine:

```js
return this.http.get(astronautsUri).pipe(
  flatMap((newAstronauts: any) => newAstronauts.people),
  filter((astronaut: Astronaut) => astronaut.craft === 'ISS'),
  map((astronaut: Astronaut) => [astronaut]),
  reduce((prev, next) => [...prev, ...next]),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

But in this case, I have to manually set the interval with `setInterval()` in the component class that renders astronauts, and I have to call the `getAstronauts()` method. So, there are two calls of the method in `ngOnInit`, basically.

How can I achieve the desired effect with just RxJS operators? I want to set up an interval, map and filter and reduce the array of objects, and then receive them.

My understanding of how RxJS mapping works is really bad, but I tried (for the sake of trying) all these methods - `switchMap()`, `concatMap()`, `exhaustMap()`, `flatMap()` - to map numbers from `interval()` to an AJAX request. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is

```
getAstronauts(): Observable<Astronaut[]> {
    return interval(5000).pipe(
      concatMap(num => 
        this.http.get(astronautsUri).pipe(
          flatMap((newAstronauts: any) => newAstronauts.people),
          filter((astronaut: Astronaut) => astronaut.craft === 'ISS'),
          reduce((prev, astronaut) => [...prev, astronaut], []),
        )
      ),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

the problem of reduce method is it is waiting for its source observable to complete, before emiting any value. in my code source is elements of one request and in question example source is all elements from all requests, which never ends

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what many people may not like - nested pipes. Although there's no other approach, I assume. It works fine, so thanks again.

Comment: it is possible to achieve with the help of `windowTime` operator, as you know that all those array items will come through the 5000 interval. You'll get 1 level of nesting, but it can be a bit buggy if some request take too long to complete

Answer (score 0):

Change reduce to scan, scan does the same thing as reduce but emits on each iteration, reduce only emits once the whole stream completes.

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { scan } = rxjs.operators;

const obs$ = from([1,2,3,4,5]);

obs$.pipe(scan((total, item) => total + item)).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

```js
const { from } = rxjs;
const { reduce } = rxjs.operators;

const obs$ = from([1,2,3,4,5]);

obs$.pipe(reduce((total, item) => total + item)).subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `scan()` does return the intermediate value, but the array gets larger all the time because the same astronaut objects get pushed into it.